# How to add RequiredExpressionValidator to the "Cantitate" field

Tags: c#, html

I have a shopping cart that can be updated by the user. I want to add a validation method to the "Cantitate" field, so that the user can only add positive integers.

html

```
<asp:GridView ID="CartList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="4"
        ItemType="Magazin.Models.CartItem" SelectMethod="GetShoppingCartItems"
        CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="Nr. articol" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.ProductName" HeaderText="Denumire" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.UnitPrice" HeaderText="Preț (per bucată)" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantitate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseQuantity" Width="40" runat="server" Text="<%#: Item.Quantity %>"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total de plată pentru acest produs">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#: String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.Product.UnitPrice)))%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Șterge">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Remove" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the UpdateCartItems:

```
 public List<CartItem> UpdateCartItems()
        {
            using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                String cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetCartId();

                ShoppingCartActions.ShoppingCartUpdates[] cartUpdates = new ShoppingCartActions.ShoppingCartUpdates[CartList.Rows.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < CartList.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    IOrderedDictionary rowValues = new OrderedDictionary();
                    rowValues = GetValues(CartList.Rows[i]);
                    cartUpdates[i].ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(rowValues["ProductID"]);

                    CheckBox cbRemove = new CheckBox();
                    cbRemove = (CheckBox)CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("Remove");
                    cartUpdates[i].RemoveItem = cbRemove.Checked;

                    TextBox quantityTextBox = new TextBox();
                    quantityTextBox = (TextBox)CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("PurchaseQuantity");
                    cartUpdates[i].PurchaseQuantity = Convert.ToInt16(quantityTextBox.Text.ToString());
                }
                usersShoppingCart.UpdateShoppingCartDatabase(cartId, cartUpdates);
                CartList.DataBind();
                lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetTotal());
                return usersShoppingCart.GetCartItems();
            }
        }
```

The update button of the shopping cart, that updates the cart by calling the UpdateCartItems

```
     protected void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateCartItems();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="CartList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Nr. articol" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantitate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="YourTextBox" runat="server" />

                            <asp:CompareValidator runat="server"
                                ControlToValidate="YourTextBox"
                                Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                                Type="Integer"
                                ErrorMessage="Enter a valid integer"
                                Display="Dynamic" />

                            <asp:CompareValidator runat="server"
                                ControlToValidate="YourTextBox"
                                Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
                                ValueToCompare="0"
                                Type="Integer"
                                ErrorMessage="The integer cannot be less than zero"
                                Display="Dynamic" />
                            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseQuantity" Width="40" runat="server" Text="" TextMode="Number" min="0"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="PurchaseQuantity" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid value" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\s+\d{1,6}\s+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I tried this method too, but it didn't work. I edited the post to provide more in-depth details.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The latest one should most probably work fine. Please check.